# badge number count increament

Tags: iphone

I have implemented the local notification concept, it is working properly but there is a problem in badge number it is not increamenting automatically as notifications occurs. I have got a link where solution for this problem is given but don't know how to use it in app delegate. Following is the link... If someone know how to auto increament the badge number ,please provide me some solution.

https://github.com/csheldrick/UILocalNotification

Thanku very much.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your local notification then before registring it with the system add this line of code.

```
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber+ 1;
```

and then you register you notification with the system

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

localNotif is object of

```
UILocalNotification
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=application.applicationIconBadgeNumber+1;
}
```

i hope it will help ful to you